# A keyboard shortcut in VS2005/8 for "Exit Current Method"

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, keyboard, shortcut

When debugging, a trick I do whenever I want to exit the current method without running of its any statements, I move the current execution pointer to the end of the method, then click F10/11.

Is there a keyboard shortcut (or can I program one) to accomplish this?

(I don't mean shift-F11 (step out) - that does run all the code until the method's end, which I do not want).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following sequence of keystrokes works for me (tested in Visual Studio 2008); I was able to record them as a temporary macro and play them back successfully:

1. `Ctrl+M, Ctrl+M` (Edit.ToggleOutliningExpansion: collapses the current method)
2. `Right arrow` (skips past the collapsed parameter list)
3. `Ctrl+]` (Edit.GotoBrace: goes to the opening brace)
4. `Ctrl+]` (Edit.GotoBrace: goes to the closing brace)
5. `Ctrl+Shift+F10` (Debug.SetNextStatement: sets the next statement to the closing brace at the end of the function)
6. `F10` (Debug.StepOver: leaves the method)

Comment: (This doesn't work on VS2005 btw - I get "unable to set the next statement to this location the next statement cannot be set to another function")

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK that's the only way to do it.